# не работает метод класса

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

я написал простой скрипт который вносит ip клиента в БД
но мне захотелось переписать его в ооп стиле

```
include('db.php');

class ClientIp
{
  function getIp ()
  {
      $client = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
      $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
      $remote = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " local";

      if (filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $client;
      elseif (filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $forward;
      else $ip = $remote;

      return $ip;
    }
  }

$ip = new ClientIp;
echo $ip->getIp();

$setIp = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO guest_ip (ip) VALUES (:ip)");
$setIp->bindParam(':ip',  $ip->getIp());
$setIp->execute();
```

вот так это работает но я продолжил и добавил метод **saveIp()**

теперь это выглядит так но это не работает

```
include('db.php');

class ClientIp
{
  static function getIp ()
  {
      $client = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
      $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
      $remote = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " local";

      if (filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $client;
      elseif (filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $forward;
      else $ip = $remote;

      return $ip;
    }
    function saveIp () {
        $setIp = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO guest_ip (ip) VALUES (:ip)");
        $setIp->bindParam(':ip',  ClientIp::getIp());
        $setIp->execute();
    }
  }

$ip = new ClientIp;
echo $ip->getIp();
$ip->saveIp();
```

что не так ?

Comment: А `$db` в методе откуда возьмется? И какой смысл писать в методе `ClientIp::` если можно писать `self::`.

Comment: @u_mulder include('db.php'); от туда эта переменная $db и self:: тоже не сработало

Comment: Вы понимаете что метод `saveIp` понятия не имеет что где-то там есть `$db`? С областью видимости переменных в php вы вообще знакомы?

Comment: а все спасибо вот так работает saveIp ($_bind_db), $ip->saveIp($db);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
include('db.php');

class ClientIp
{
    public function getIp ()
    {
        $client = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $remote = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " local";

        if (filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $client;
        elseif (filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $forward;
        else $ip = $remote;

        return $ip;
    }
    public function saveIp(&$database) {
        $setIp = $databse->prepare("INSERT INTO guest_ip (ip) VALUES (:ip)");
        $setIp->bindParam(':ip', $this->getIp());
        $setIp->execute();
    }
}

$ip = new ClientIp;
echo $ip->getIp();
$ip->saveIp($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка тут:

```
$ip = new ClientIp;
echo $ip->getIp();
```

у вас функция:

```
static function getIp ()
```

Объявлена как static, убрать нужно. А вообще, хорошо бы ошибки показать, а то так сложно.

Comment: у меня php 7.5 и static не влияет дело в переменной $db в методе saveIp ее не видно

Comment: 7.5, из будущего пишете что ли?

Comment: @u_mulder я тоже в начале не понял, но решил не ковырять дальше, а ведь вы правы, нет не какого 7.5 PHP, текущий релиз вроде 7.3.3